# convert crystal report in pdf file

Tags: crystal-reports

I have problem in crystal report. I have three Pages A.aspx,B.aspx and C.aspx.

when I clicked on submit button in A.aspx I want save A.aspx data in Sample.pdf file and redirect to B.aspx. After that when I clicked on submit button in B.aspx I want save A.aspx and B.aspx data in Sample.pdf file(or attached B.aspx crystal report to Sample.pdf) and redirect to C.aspx. and finaly when I 
Clicked on Submit button in C.aspx i want to attache this C.aspx crystal report to Sample.pdf. Means attach or merge three crystal report in one Sample.pdf. and send this file to my mail Id.

Please help me.

Regards,

Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Question is did u attach The sub- reports to Each and Every page

Go to design page in each Report go to Sub report Column

Right Click On the Sub - report !

**Unchecked the On demand Sub-report**

If so go to

File

Export

On click Export

select PDF

and save it

Comment: Hello mokri,when I export report to Pdf only one report exported. I want to export all 3 report in one pdf file. Please help me